# Player doesnt move when i add my background to a canvas layer node

Tags: game-development, godot, godot4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqaTv.png)I am new to godot and i started learning from a udemy course.
I tried to add a background to my scene and when i made it a child of a canvaslayer node,
my player movement stoppped working. More specifically, this only happened when i set the layer of the canvas layer to a number below 0.

here's my player movement script:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    var player_speed = 200
    var direction_list = [0 ,0]
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Up"):
        direction_list[1] -= 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Down"):
        direction_list[1] += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Right"):
        direction_list[0] += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Left"):
        direction_list[0] -= 1
        
    apply_force(Vector2(direction_list[0] * player_speed, direction_list[1] * player_speed))[no player movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A9wo.png)
```

when i remove the canvas layer, it works but the course uses one...
i hope someone can help me

Comment: the player does move, but  it is not being displayed

Comment: That might be because the background is being rendered above the player.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a representation or screenshot of the exact node structure.

Answer (score 0):

The background node is probably displayed above the player node. Try setting the player’s Visibility “Top Level” on so it displays above other node in its parent class.

Comment: that didnt work